# Ethereum eth_call returns padded address

Tags: ethereum, web3js

This is my Contract ABI

```
 abi:[{
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "owner",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "address",
          "name": "",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function",
      "constant": true
    }]
```

when I try get the address of the owner using **eth_call** method of ***ethereum.request***(...) its giving me the padded address instead of the real address,

getting `0x000000000000000000000000ed3a7bb89eb3e355bed8975c5ff03e39d1c91c75`
instead of `0xed3a7bb89eb3e355bed8975c5ff03e39d1c91c75`

how to convert the output of method call to ethereum address?

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum address is 20 bytes (40 hex characters) long. But each of the EVM storage slots has a capacity of 32 bytes (64 hex characters).

`eth_call` returns the raw data from the storage slot, doesn't adjust for datatype size. That's why there's the padding.

---

You can use the web3 [decodeParameter()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-abi.html#decodeparameter) function to parse the address:

```
// returns "0xed3a7bb89eB3e355beD8975c5Ff03e39D1C91C75"
const address = web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter(
    'address',
    '0x000000000000000000000000ed3a7bb89eb3e355bed8975c5ff03e39d1c91c75'
);
```

And because both address and storage slot sizes are fixed, you can also use the regular JS `slice()` function to parse a substring (from the 26th position including the leading `0x`).

```
// returns "0xed3a7bb89eB3e355beD8975c5Ff03e39D1C91C75"
const address = '0x' + '0x000000000000000000000000ed3a7bb89eb3e355bed8975c5ff03e39d1c91c75'.slice(26);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decode all the data as per the ABI.json

```js
const output= window.ethereum.eth.request({method: "eth_call",params: [tx]});
let outputsTypes = this.contract.methods[method](...args)._method.outputs;
const result= window.ethereum.eth.abi.decodeParameters(outputsTypes, output);
```